# JavaScript and semicolon

Tags: node.js, typeerror, strict

```
'use strict'
[1,2,3,4].find(x => x > 1)
```

When the above code is executed with Node.js 5.0.0, it gives the following error:

```
TypeError: "use strict"[(((1 , 2) , 3) , 4)].find is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\src\nodejs\ecma6.js:2:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
at startup (node.js:136:18)
at node.js:972:3
```

The error goes away if I add a semicolon after 'use strict'.

This looks like a bug... Or is there anything deeper - meaning whether there is a list of exceptional cases in the language specification, in which a semicolon is required.

The language specification does list exceptional cases, in which explicit semicolons are required.

Comment: The compiler didn't fail here. It's listed in the language specification in 7.9.1 part 1.

Comment: This is just an example where JS programmer has decided to drop the semicolon and pretend that it's okay. Javascript statements *require* using semicolons but it also has autocorrect feature called Automatic Semicolon Insertion (ASI) which some programmers consider to be a feature they're *supposed* to use. It's like intentionally always speling wrods incorectly and asuming it's fien becayse there's autocorect systme. In this case, dropping the semicolon is not okay because next line starts with a `[` which is one of the characters in the JS spec that prevent this autocorrection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one reason why it is always advised to use semicolons in javascript. The reason it doesn't work is because the code is interpreted as:

```
"use strict"[1,2,3,4] ...
```

In other words it's interpreted as:

```
"use strict"[4] ...
```

because of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/my/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). This evaluates to the string `"s"`.

Now, the rest of the code is trying to do:

```
"s".find()
```

but strings don't have the find method.

To avoid all this, make sure you tell the interpreter that the two lines are separate statements - use a semicolon.

---

#### Additional note:

This behavior is required by the ECMAScript standards (at least ES5). In section 7.9.1 part 1 the rules governing this case is defined:

> When, as the program is parsed from left to right, a token (called the offending token) is encountered that is not allowed by any production of the grammar, then a semicolon is automatically inserted before the offending token if one or more of the following conditions is true:
>
> 1. The offending token is separated from the previous token by at least one LineTerminator.
> 2. The offending token is }.

In this case, the `"use strict"` and `[1,2,3,4]...` is parsed. The compiler looks at the resulting statement:

```
"use strict"[1,2,3,4]...
```

and notes that this is valid javascript. Therefore a semicolon is not inserted since no "offending token" is found in the statement.

Comment: Never trust semicolon insertion in a language where the rules for semicolon insertion are too complex for humans to keep track. It's OK for languages like go etc. but IMHO not OK for javascript.

Comment: Because a string's contents can be accessed by index just like an array.  "astring"[0] == "a".  Likewise, "astring"[0,1,2] == "t".

Comment: @PeterPeiGuo: The compiler didn't fail. The programmer failed to realize that strings can be accessed using `foo[bar]` syntax.

Comment: @PeterPeiGuo: Another common case I've seen often is `var x=function(){}(function(){}())` <-- this doesn't do what you think it does. The second function is not an IIFE - the first function is an IIFE and it's called by passing the second function as its argument.

Comment: @PeterPeiGuo: That's the problem about semicolon insertion. In javascript, semicolon insertion works via exception/errors. The interpreter tries to add the next line and if it doesn't make sense syntactically then it's considered as part of the previous statement. If it generates a syntax error then the two lines are separated and parsed again. If it still generates a syntax error then the compiler will output a syntax error otherwise it will continue parsing. This is of course very silly - it makes code perfectly parseable to the compiler but ambiguous to humans.

Comment: @PeterPeiGuo: So in this case the compiler is merely implementing the specification. It's the specification that's buggy (semicolon insertion)

Comment: @PeterPeiGuo: See: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9. Specifically 7.9.1 part 1. It describes the mechanism I mentioned above. The compiler is not buggy. It's the programmer's mistake for misunderstanding how the syntax works. To avoid such mistakes I advocate always using semicolons. It's not your fault. It's the fault of the standards.

Comment: @PeterPeiGuo: It's not impossible for the compiler to recognise the boundary but the standard requires the two lines to be a single statement.